# Xades4j signing xml files with attachments

Tags: java, xades4j

is there posibility to sign xml document with attachments without baseURI?

Code:

```
        SignedDataObjects signedDataObjects = new SignedDataObjects();
        DataObjectReference dataObjectReference = new DataObjectReference("");
        dataObjectReference.withTransform(new DataObjectTransform("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"));
        signedDataObjects.withSignedDataObject(dataObjectReference);
        signedDataObjects.withBaseUri(baseUri + File.separator);

        attachments.forEach(attachment -> {
            DataObjectDesc dataObjectReferenceForAttachment = new DataObjectReference(attachment.getName());
            signedDataObjects.withSignedDataObject(dataObjectReferenceForAttachment);
        });

        XadesSigner signer = profile.newSigner();
        signer.sign(signedDataObjects, xmlDocument.getDocumentElement());
```

I'd like to skip the line:

```
signedDataObjects.withBaseUri(baseUri + File.separator);
```

It is possible to send attachments in the form of byte []? There can be many such attachments. Unfortunately I am not able to save files to disk.

Answer (score 0):

One important question to ask is: how is this signature going to be verified? If there's flexibility for some custom resource resolution at verification, I suggest using a custom URI scheme and a custom resource resolver.

```
// Only once
signedDataObjects.withResourceResolver(new AttachmentsResolver(attachments));
// In the loop
DataObjectDesc dataObjectReferenceForAttachment = new DataObjectReference("attachment:" + attachment.getName());
```

The custom resolver checks if the URI is `attachment:` and gets the contents for the given name from the `attachments` collection.

Example: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/test/java/xades4j/production/SignedDataObjectsProcessorTest.java

Reference: http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.6.0/reference/xades4j/production/SignedDataObjects.html#withResourceResolver(org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverSpi)

If the verification end can't have logic to handle custom URIs, then I suggest embedding the attachments in the XML using `EnvelopedXmlObject`.

Side-notes:

- There's an `EnvelopedSignatureTransform` class that you can use.
- The `withNNN` methods allow you write stuff fluently.

  ```
  new DataObjectReference("").withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());
  ```